# Нужны ли кавычки или двоеточие в этом предложении?

Tags: кавычки, двоеточие

Скажите, нужно ли употреблять кавычки или двоеточие в предложении? И почему?

> Юноша, как отметил Райт, встал в стойку и представился: «имя».

Будет ли этот вариант считаться правильным?

Answer (score 3):

Двоеточие и кавычки нужны, потому что имеется глагол говорения "представился", предваряющий прямую речь.

Answer (score 1):

Прямая речь здесь **нераспространенная**, поэтому возможны **разные варианты** оформления.

К примеру, мне в Нацорпусе встретились такие:

(1) *После концерта в каком-то Доме культуры за кулисами к Алле подошел худой человек и представился: **композитор Александр Зацепин**.* [Алексей Беляков. Алка, Аллочка, Алла Борисовна (1998)]

(2) *...он подскочил ко мне, пожал руку и представился: **― Никита!*** [Татьяна Соломатина. Мой одесский язык (2011)]

В первом варианте дословное высказывание оформлено **как БСП** (бессоюзное сложное предложение).